# Filter a pandas dataframe by a boolean function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I need to filter a pandas dataframe using a function on only one column of string.

Here an example of dataframe :

```
  ID  Titles    Values
0  1  title1   value1
1  2  title2   value2
2  3  title3   value3
...
```

I have a complex function :

```
def checkTitle(title:str) -> bool :
    ...
```

And I want to filter the first dataframe with this function on the column Titles, with only the rows where the function send True.

I try something like that but it doesn't return anything usable :

```
df = df.apply(checkTitle(df["Titles"]),axis=1)
```

Can you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a solution for you.

```
def checkTitle(title:str) -> bool:
    if title == 'title2':
        return True
    else:
        return False

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Titles': ['title1', 'title2', 'title2', 'title3'], 'Values': ['value1', 'value2', 'value2', 'value3']})

mask = df.Titles.apply(checkTitle)
df[mask]
```

I don't know your function in detail, but you need to return both bool values True|False to slice the dataframe.

I hope this solution helps

Regards,

Comment: you can simply your function with `return title == 'title2'`

Comment: Hey @Paul H, you’re right. However, you need both True and False to use the function as a mask. I don’t know Matou’s function so I use that one as a dummy. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @diegogiraldog Thank you for your solution, I will test after tonight. And little additionnal question : if the function checkTitle is a method from a class `def checkTitle(self,title:str) -> bool:`, how I can apply it because it needs the "self" argument ?

Comment: Hey @Matou, could you share the code? It's difficult to answer the question without a bit of context.

Comment: It's ok, I found the solution, I just need to use "lambda" into the apply and it's working. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the function to just one column of the dataframe and then use the resulting Boolean series to select the rows:

```py
select = df.Titles.apply(checkTitle)
df = df.loc[select, :]
```